# C# How to find a Class' non created objects?

Tags: c#, class, linked-list

I have this class

```
class Node
{
    public bool is_end;
    public int prefix_count;
    public Node[] child = new Node[26];
}
```

My problem is, the class only creates Nodes if it is necessary, but later in the program, i need to check all the created Nodes, though since i don't know which ones are created, i can't use a cycle for it.

Is there a way for me to know which Nodes are created, is there a code to check if this Node exists or not.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you are asking. Are you trying to see _all_ the `Node` objects in your program? Or just the ones in your `child` array?

Comment: I have to find out which child nodes are created, for example a cycle from 0 to 25, and it has to give a message like node[2] and node[11] are created, others aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, your `child` array is pre-created, but each individual node is not allocated.  You can check for `null` to see if a `Node` has been created:

```
bool ChildCreated(Node parent, int childIndex)
{
    return parent.child[childIndex] != null;
}
```

---

> I have to find out which child nodes are created, for example a cycle from 0 to 25, and it has to give a message like node[2] and node[11] are created, others aren't.

Using this method, you could easily do:

```
var created = Enumerable.Range(0, node.child.Length).Where(i => ChildCreated(node, i)).ToList();
if (!created.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine("No children created.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Children {0} created, all others aren't.", string.Join(", ", created));
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if i send index of a non-created child object, it gives null reference exception, since the object isn't created, it won't let me compare it with null, thats the problem.

Comment: @imdrunkisuppose The snippet here will only throw a null reference exception if `parent` is null, or if the `child` property itself is null. Any element in `child` can be null, simply accessing an element with a null value does not produce an exception.

Comment: @imdrunkisuppose You could always add a check for parent being null, but I doubt that's going to be a problem in practice...

Comment: @imdrunkisuppose From what you mentioned in your comment, this will allow you to do that - I'll add code to demo

Answer (score 4):

Try using a `List<Node>` instead of a fixed length array. Then you can use methods such as

```
var nodeList = new List<Node>();
nodeList.Add(someRandomNode);
if (nodeList.Contains(someRandomNode)) 
{
    // your logic
}
```

You may also iterate over your `Node` collection.

```
foreach(var node in nodeList) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to check if `Node[]` element is null:

```
int nodeIndex = 0;
if(child[nodeIndex] == null)
{
    // node doesn't exist
}
else
{
    // node exists
}
```